# "libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python3' for plugin" when loading a pluging in gedit

Tags: gedit, python3

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and I use gedit for a lot of things.

I was trying to install some plugins that I use quite frequently and I came into some issues.

First I installed the plugins like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

I can see the plugins in gedit but when I choose to use a plugin via the edit>preferences>plugins menu this message shows up:

```
(gedit:6027): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python3' for plugin    
'codecomment'
```

I know I have python3 installed because when I type python3 in my terminal I get:

```
 Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:32:14) 
 [GCC 4.7.3] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>>
```

I also have python 2.7.4, by similar terminal command.

If anyone can help me get these plugins up and running in gedit I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 12.04 and Gedit 3.4.1, but with a different plug-in.

This is how I resolved it: Find the file `[plugin-name]*.plugin` in gedit's plugin directory and edit the line `Loader=python3`  to `Loader=python`

My gedit plugin-dir was under `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/` if it helps.

Comment: I had a problem with another plugin (`gedit-reflow`) and the *opposite* change worked. (`gedit 3.8`)

Comment: Ditto I for `ipython` -- I had to use `Loader=python3`

Answer (score 0):

Might you have your Python virtual environment messing up the plugins as I had?

I got plugins like `codecomment` working by hiding my `PYTHONPATH` and python virtual environment before launching Gedit.

Since I still want to use my venv I have an executable script 'gedit' in my path with

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH= PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games /usr/bin/gedit "$@"
```

At least this way the plugins work for me. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Gedit 3.10.4.