# gedit-developer-plugins on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander

Tags: 13.10, gedit, plugins

I've installed **gedit-developer-plugins** on a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander

I've lauched **gedit** (from the terminal) but when I turn a GDP plugin on (in this case GDP Find) I get the following error:

> (gedit:3640): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python' for plugin 'gdpfind'

The same error only shows while turning on GDP plugins, the others work well.

Any solution to make this plugins work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that the old plugin (0.5.15) use the python provided by old gedit (3.6)

it's possible to get the stable plugins (1.1.0) that with with gedit (3.8.3) in saucy at
https://launchpad.net/~sinzui/+archive/ppa

Just run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sinzui/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gedit-developer-plugins
```

And then you can turn the GDP plugins on.

**EDIT for UBUNTU 14.04**

To enable GDP Format plugin you must install [python-pocket-lint](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-pocket-lint), just run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pocket-lint
```

If you are in a hurry, just do everything in one command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:sinzui/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install gedit-developer-plugins python-pocket-lint
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid things may depend on the developer responsible for the plugin. But, you could first try the solution presented here: [Problem With Gedit Plugins and Python3 on 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/302431/25656).

I updated to `Lubuntu 13.10` and installed the gedit version available in the software center (v 3.8.3). Then I tried to install [doublesave](https://askubuntu.com/a/308256/25656) and [markdown-preview](http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/gedit-markdown.php) both of which worked for me in Lubuntu 13.04. I ran into the same problem as you and changing `Loader=` as suggested in the first link didn't help me.

I did an internet search and concluded that the issue maybe something that [the individual plugin developer](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=106975#p510765) has to modify unless the `Loader=` fix works for you.

Comment: I've tried the `Loader=` solution without any luck
Sadly, I think it's a plugin problem

Comment: Well, I've started using geany. It has the equivalent plugins I need. Why don't you take a look? `apt-cache --names-only geany` will give you a list of the plugins easily available.