# Gedit external tools plugin failed to load

Tags: gedit

I had gedit configured with some plugins but after upgrading to 13.10, every time I go the gedit Plugins and try to load the external tools I get a message saying: Failed to Load.

Not sure how to fix this. Tried reinstalling but this didn't help

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/362420/is-it-just-me-or-are-the-gedit-plugins-in-13-10-incomplete for leads

Comment: Thanks, this cleared few things up but I haven't been able to find a fix for it yet.. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg4210074.html), try installing gir1.2-gtksource-3.0. 
It worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed the package gir1.2-gtksource-3.0, but the External Tools Manager didn't work, I had to change permissions to this directory:

`sudo chown <username> /home/<username>/.config/gedit`